# Trying to initialize an Image

Tags: ios, swift

[This is me clicking "fix"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdbA7.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOgsP.png)
I created a new class and init method for my data with 3 variables. One being the `UIImage`. It can't seem to locate the images in my assets folder.

I tried `UIimage(named:  String)`.

Below is my Code

```
    class DataForMeals {
    var mealName: String
    var mealImage: UIImage
    var description: String

    init(mealName: String, mealImage: UIImage, description: String) {
        self.mealImage = mealImage
        self.mealName = mealName
        self.description = description
    }

class func mealData() ->[DataForMeals] {
        var meal: [DataForMeals] = []

        let meal1 = DataForMeals(mealName: "", mealImage: UIImage(named: ""),description: "")
```

It's supposed to find the image by name.

Comment: `UIImage(named: "")` your image has no name?

Comment: `mealName` and name of the `mealImage` are the same? If `mealName` is `xyz`, do you want to get the image named `xyz`

Comment: `UIImage(named: "")`should be `UIImage(named: "whateveryourImageisCalled")` this name should be the same as is defined in your Assets folder without any extension

Comment: hey @ReinierMelian i tried that, still shoots out an error and forces me to unwrap. Tried other methods to force unwrap but it makes it hard to append the array.

Comment: you need to add this line `import UIKit` in your class you can't use classes from UIKit without import statement, please let me know if this solves your issue

Comment: already had UIkit from the beginning @ReinierMelian.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `empty string ("")` in as `imageName` while creating the `UIImage` object, you need to give the name of actual `image` that resides in your `Assets.xcassets`

**Example:**

[image]

To get the `image1` from `assets`, you need to use:

```
UIImage(named: "image1")
```

The `name` should **exactly match** with the `name of image in Assets.xcassets`

**Edit-1:**

`UIImage init()` is a **`failable initialiser`** and so it `return` an `optional UIImage` object i.e. `UIImage?`. So you need to `unwrap` the `image` before using it, i.e.

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "frenchtoast") {
    let meal1 = DataForMeals(mealName: "French Toast", mealImage: image,description: "recipe")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I do have a filename, I just took it out because it hints what the project is about. But that does not work either.

Comment: Please check the image attached.

Comment: Updated the answer. Look into it,.

Comment: Do accept (tick on left) if it works for you. Happy coding 

Comment: Hey @PGDev, I'm doing everything but it still isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for calling the image from the assets.

```
UIImage(named: "image1")
```

In your case, you need to pass the image name

```
let meal1 = DataForMeals(mealName: "Roti", mealImage: UIImage(named: "name1"),description: "Afternoon Meal")
```

Comment: please check the image attached.